# Information not showing on notification click android

Tags: android

I am trying to make app where I am making server req and getting response, while I am getting response I showed it with notification even if apps killed. So this is why I made all this in service and after getting response I broadcast info got from server response to broadcastreceiver in activity to show info in a recyclerview.info showing while in apps on(no click on notification but continuous network req and response) as i made direct broadcast but while I click on notification nothing showing in recyclerview. how to solve this ..

NotificationActivity:

```
public class NotificationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    GetPostAsyncTask backgroundTask;
    ArrayList<NotificationDataClass> list;
    NotificationListShowAdapter notificationListShowAdapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Context contextNotificationActivity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification);

        Intent intent=new Intent(NotificationActivity.this,ServiceClass.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startService(intent);
        contextNotificationActivity=NotificationActivity.this;

        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewId);

        /*notificationListShowAdapter=new NotificationListShowAdapter(contextNotificationActivity,list);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(contextNotificationActivity);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(notificationListShowAdapter);
        DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(contextNotificationActivity,
                layoutManager.getOrientation());
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
        notificationListShowAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();*/

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver,new IntentFilter("Notification"));
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {


        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Toast.makeText(context,"Receiver",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            String result=intent.getStringExtra("Result");
            Log.v("Brd",intent.getStringExtra("Result"));
            JSONObject jsonObject= null;
            list=new ArrayList<>();
            try {

                jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
//                JSONObject codeObj=jsonObject.optJSONObject("code");
                JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("payload");


                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject jsonObject1=new JSONObject(jsonArray.optString(i));


                    NotificationDataClass notificationDataClass=new NotificationDataClass();
                    notificationDataClass.setName(jsonObject1.getString("Name"));
                    notificationDataClass.setRemarks(jsonObject1.getString("Remarks"));
                    Log.v("hsdgfjgsdh", String.valueOf(jsonObject1.getInt("Type")));
                    if(jsonObject1.getInt("Type")==1){
                        notificationDataClass.setInout("In");
                    }else {
                        notificationDataClass.setInout("Out");
                    }

                    notificationDataClass.setTime(jsonObject1.getString("DateTime"));


                    list.add(i,notificationDataClass);

                }

                notificationListShowAdapter=new NotificationListShowAdapter(context,list);
                LinearLayoutManager layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(context);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(notificationListShowAdapter);
                DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(context,
                        layoutManager.getOrientation());
                recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
                notificationListShowAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    }
}
```

serviceClass:

```
public class ServiceClass extends Service {

    GetPostAsyncTask_ServiceClass backgroundTask;
    Context context;
    Handler handler;
    Runnable runnable;
    LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager;


    int iny=1;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        localBroadcastManager=LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        context=getApplicationContext();

        handler=new Handler();

        runnable=new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                String queryForNotification=null;


                try {
                    queryForNotification = URLEncoder.encode("dateTime", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("03/13/2017", "UTF-8");

                    Log.v("INRTR","out"+iny++);

                    backgroundTask=new GetPostAsyncTask_ServiceClass(context);

                    backgroundTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,"GET","GetHrOnDutyActivityByDate?"+queryForNotification,"");

                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

//                ((Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(1000);

                handler.postDelayed(runnable,10000);
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(runnable,10000);

        return START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }





    //Asynctask
    private class GetPostAsyncTask_ServiceClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

//        public AsyncResult asyncResult;
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        private final String baseUrl = "http://192.168.0.6:880/MobileAPI/";


        Context context;


        GetPostAsyncTask_ServiceClass(Context context) {

            this.context = context;
//            this.asyncResult = asyncResult;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //Toast.makeText(context,"Loading..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
//        progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            try {
                // setting the URL
                URL url = new URL(baseUrl + args[1]);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.addRequestProperty("Apiuser", "SDLPayrollAPI");
                httpURLConnection.addRequestProperty("Apikey", "DFGHJ*UH45445^TY");

                // setting the method type
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(args[0]);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

                // setting the identification key name with query params
                bufferedWriter.write(args[2]);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();

                httpURLConnection.connect();

                String line = "";
                String res = "";

                // prepare the output buffer
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));

                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                    res += line;

                }

                inputStream.close();

                httpURLConnection.disconnect();

                return res.toString();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.v("PesDSS","doBCa"+e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Log.v("PesDSS","out"+result);



            Intent intent1;
//            progressDialog.dismiss();
            if (result != null) {
//                asyncResult.asyncResult(result);
                Log.v("PesDSS","in"+result);

                //notification

                NotificationCompat.Builder notification=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.systech_logo)
                .setContentTitle("Notification")
                .setContentText("Delivered")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                ;

                intent1 = new Intent(context, NotificationActivity.class);
                intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent1.setAction("Notification");

                intent1.putExtra("Result",result);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent1);


                TaskStackBuilder taskStackBuilder=TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
                taskStackBuilder.addParentStack(NotificationActivity.class);
                taskStackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent1);

                PendingIntent pendingIntent=taskStackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
//                PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

                notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

                NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.notify(0,notification.build());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notification data class:

```
public class NotificationDataClass {

    String name;
    String remarks;
    String inout;
    String time;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getRemarks() {
        return remarks;
    }

    public void setRemarks(String remarks) {
        this.remarks = remarks;
    }

    public String getInout() {
        return inout;
    }

    public void setInout(String inout) {
        this.inout = inout;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

I tried to follow solutions from Stack Overflow but I could not solve it. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

FYI `onReceive()` is called only when your current activity is in foreground or visible. For doing task on click of notification, when your activity/app is in background you should also do the same thing in `onCreate()` which you have done in `onReceive()` like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification);
        Intent notificationIntent = getIntent.getStringExtra("Result");
        if(notificationIntent != null){
            //do whatever you have done in onReceive().
        }
}
```

Comment: but what to do if my app is killed? @Megha MInar

Comment: Answer looks okay .

Comment: Have you made any class for handling notification which extends either `FirebaseMessagingService` or `GCMIntentService`?

Comment: @MeghaManiar no. i posted all class here related this issue

Comment: @MeghaManiar this also showing same result, i mean not showing anything

Comment: Are you receiving notifications from server or are you generating notifications within the application?

Comment: receiving from server and if response get then only showing notification

Comment: Yes, so where have you done that? I mean in which class have you done that??

Comment: ServiceClass which extending from service and i posted that class above @MeghaManiar

Comment: try like this in your service class:
`intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);`